# $SU(2)$ as an algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

The $\mathbb R$-valued points of the algebraic group $SU(2)$ can be identified with the real 3-sphere.  But how does one define $SU(2)$ over the base field $\mathbb R$ as an algebraic group?  What are its defining equations?  What is the Hopf algebra structure on its coordinate ring?

Comment: You can represent it in terms of real matrices by just representing it in terms of complex matrices, then represent the complex numbers as 2 by 2 real matrices. Is that what you sought for the first question?

Comment: @rschwieb: That only gives you the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1$ for the real points which is the equation of the sphere.  I am looking for the coordinate ring as a real variety and the hopf algebra structure.

Comment: Dear @piete : you will probably have to be more specific about your first question then, since that seems to be a perfectly fine way to exhibit the group using the reals. I saw the other two questions, but I cannot help you address them. I am only talking about the first question.

Answer (score 2):

You can equate $SU(2)$ with the group of unit quaternions. If you do it that way, then the
coordinate ring becomes
$$
\Gamma=\Bbb{R}[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]/\langle x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-1\rangle.
$$
The neutral element is $1$, so the counit is given by
$$
\varepsilon: \Gamma\to\Bbb{R}, x_0\mapsto1, x_\ell\mapsto0,\ell=1,2,3.
$$
The inverse of the quaternion $q=x_0+x_1i+x_2j+x_3k$ is its conjugate, so the antipode is determined by
$$
S:\Gamma\to\Gamma, x_0\mapsto x_0,\ x_\ell\mapsto -x_\ell, \ell=1,2,3.
$$
The product of $q$ and $q'=x_0'+x_1'i+x_2'j+x_3'k$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
qq'&=(x_0x_0'-x_1x_1'-x_2x_2'-x_3x_3')+\\
&+(x_0x_1'+x_1x_0'+x_2x_3'-x_3x_2')i+\\
&+(x_0x_2'+x_2x_0'-x_1x_3'+x_3x_1')j+\\
&+(x_0x_3'+x_3x_0'+x_1x_2'-x_2x_1')k.
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies that the coproduct $\Delta:\Gamma\to\Gamma\otimes_{\Bbb{R}}\Gamma$ is determined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(x_0)&=x_0\otimes x_0-x_1\otimes x_1-x_2\otimes x_2-x_3\otimes x_3,\\
\Delta(x_1)&=x_0\otimes x_1+x_1\otimes x_0+x_2\otimes x_3-x_3\otimes x_2,\\
\Delta(x_2)&=x_0\otimes x_2+x_2\otimes x_0-x_1\otimes x_3+x_3\otimes x_1,\\
\Delta(x_3)&=x_0\otimes x_3+x_3\otimes x_0+x_1\otimes x_2-x_2\otimes x_1.\\
\end{aligned}
$$